# Count occurrences of a char in plain text file

Tags: linux, count, terminal, character

Is there any way under linux/terminal to count, how many times the char f occurs in a plain text file?

Comment: Technically this could be considered a sh/bash/etc. programming question, so I think it has validity in either place.

Comment: @Rob Hruska: yes, I also think is bash programming...

@abrashka: the answer for your first and second question is "NO"!

Answer (score 188, accepted):

How about this:

```
fgrep -o f <file> | wc -l
```

Note: Besides much easier to remember/duplicate and customize, this is about three times (sorry, edit! botched the first test) faster than Vereb's answer.

Comment: This one doesn't work if you need to count `\r` or `\n` characters; the `tr -cd f` answer does work for that.

Comment: To count several characters, e.g. `a`, `b` and `c`, use `egrep` : `egrep -o 'a|b|c' <file> | wc -l`.

Comment: Also, beware to NOT use `wc -c` as in the `tr` answer : since `grep` outputs line by line, `wc` would count end-of-lines as characters (hence doubling the number of characters).

Comment: @bjnord Ok for `\r`, but to count `\n` why not just use `wc -l` ?

Comment: Warning: `fgrep` is obsolescent; use `grep -F`. e.g. `grep -oF f <file> | wc -l`

Answer (score 77):

even faster:

```
tr -cd f < file | wc -c
```

**Time for this command** with a file with 4.9 MB and 1100000 occurences of the searched character:

```
real   0m0.089s
user   0m0.057s
sys    0m0.027s
```

Time for Vereb answer with `echo`, `cat`, `tr` and `bc` for the same file:

```
real   0m0.168s
user   0m0.059s
sys    0m0.115s
```

Time for Rob Hruska answer with `tr`, `sed` and `wc` for the same file:

```
real   0m0.465s
user   0m0.411s
sys    0m0.080s
```

Time for Jefromi answer with `fgrep` and `wc` for the same file:

```
real   0m0.522s
user   0m0.477s
sys    0m0.023s
```

Comment: To count several characters, e.g. `a`, `b` and `c` : `tr -cd abc < file | wc -l`.

Comment: are you sure? wasn't suppose to be `tr -cd abc < file | wc -c` instead

Answer (score 10):

```
echo $(cat <file>  | wc -c) - $(cat <file>  | tr -d 'A' | wc -c) | bc
```

where the A is the character

Time for this command with a file with 4.9 MB and 1100000 occurences of the searched character:

```
real   0m0.168s
user   0m0.059s
sys    0m0.115s
```

Comment: This gets about a third faster if you take out the unnecessary `cat` s, giving the filename as an argument to `wc` and `tr`.

Comment: If you realy want to optimize this reads the file just once: echo $(stat -c%s <file>) - $(cat <file> | tr -d 'A' | wc -c) | bc

Comment: @Vereb - tr only reads `stdin`, but that can be piped rather than `cat`ed: `tr -d 'A' < <file> | wc ...`

Answer (score 8):

If all you need to do is count the number of lines containing your character, this will work:

```
grep -c 'f' myfile
```

However, it counts multiple occurrences of 'f' on the same line as a single match.

Answer (score 4):

`tr -d '\n' < file | sed 's/A/A\n/g' | wc -l`

Replacing the two occurrences of "A" with your character, and "file" with your input file.

- `tr -d '\n' < file`: removes newlines
- `sed 's/A/A\n/g`: adds a newline after every occurrence of "A"
- `wc -l`: counts the number of lines

*Example:*

```
$ cat file
abcdefgabcdefgababababbbba


1234gabca

$ tr -d '\n' < file | sed 's/a/a\n/g' | wc -l
9
```