# Determine the number of characters in a variable

Tags: bash

How can I determine the number of characters in a variable?

```
FOO="blabla.bla.blabla.bla."
--check--
echo $FOO # 4 dot

FOO="..bla.bla.bla.blabla.bla."
--check--
echo $FOO # 7 dot
```

Comment: Here is your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603566/count-occurrences-of-a-char-in-plain-text-file

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
echo ${#FOO}
```

`${#VARIABLE_NAME}` gives you the lenght of a string. [Read](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) (its on top of the page)

Comment: count all characters? not only dots?

Comment: Question was : `How to determine the number of characters in a variable?`

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk -F. '{print NF-1}' <<<$FOO
```

example:

```
kent$  FOO="blabla.bla.blabla.bla."   

kent$  awk -F. '{print NF-1}' <<<$FOO
4

kent$  FOO="..bla.bla.bla.blabla.bla."

kent$  awk -F. '{print NF-1}' <<<$FOO 
7
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo $FOO | tr -dc \\. | wc -c`

Does that answer your question?

Comment: somehow I do not work :-(( ... if [ "$(echo $FOO | tr -dc \\. | wc -c)" -gt "1" ]; then ...

Comment: `export FOO="..bla.bla.bla.blabla.bla."; if [ "$(echo $FOO | tr -dc \\. | wc -c)" -gt "8" ]; then echo "more"; else echo "less"; fi`

Answer (score 0):

Strip the non-dots and count the length of the result.

```
 $ x=..bla.bla.bla.blabla.bla.
 $ _=${x//[^.]} count=${#_}; echo "$count"
7
 $ printf -v _ %s%n "${x//[^.]}" count; echo "$count"
7
```