# How to count dots in a record spanning several lines with sed?

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Let's imagine I have a text file with records taken from different sources. The file looks like this:

```
1000 Once upon a time, happy end.
1001 Tornado in NY city, the statue was finally found.
1002 I bought her an iphone 
yes 
for $1000. And then

happy end.
1003 How many times 
have I seen it?
not many. Actually.
1004 5 Cars. 2 Toys. 3 Birds.
```

Each row starts with `\n` and a row number like {1000...2000}. The row number is separated from text with a tab `\t`.

So how do I count the occurrence of `"."` with **sed** in one `record`?

Can **sed** substitute all chars except the ones that are given in a pattern without grouping them in into `[^...]`?

The output should look like this:

```
1000 1
1001 1
1002 2
1003 2
1004 3
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1603638/171318

Comment: Thanks, but it is not what I'm trying to do here. I need to count the occurrences within one record.

Comment: Ok, then I didn't got the question as it was intended

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one method:

```
$ awk -v r=1000 '{print r++,split($0,a,".")-1}' RS="\n[0-9]+\t" file 
1000 1
1001 1
1002 2
1003 2
1004 3
```

Comment: this shall count all the dots in a file, I need to count the dots within one record only. Take a notice why I assign RS in my query.

Comment: @minerals adding the expected output is always a good idea, I don't know where the tabs are in your file so I couldn't test. Please a the output `cat -t file` to your question so I know where the tabs are.

Comment: @minerals your question is much clearer now, see edit, should do the trick.

Comment: excellent, your solution worked correctly, many thanks.
As I see, the only sane way to do it, is with awk. Sed is no good

Comment: @minerals yes `awk` is definitely the tools for this.