# How to add missing characters to a line of text in a file using some scripting on UNIX?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, text-parsing

I made a program that reads data from a file and inserts them into a table.

Each line has variables and there is a comma between every two variables. Each line is a different row of the table. I want to make a unix script that will open the file with 100 lines and read every line and count  `,` that the script will find. After that i want it to edit each line and fill the line with `,` until the count of them is 50.

For example i need each line to have 50 commas (`,`). If I read a line and has it has 30 `,`, I want to add additional 20 commas to this line.

(line1)

```
9,15040113501460,0,b1          0035569144,91    302317960883,0,15040113501460,132,15040614170560,N,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0000000000000000,0,0,2,,27,b1          003st69144,1
```

(line2)

```
9,15350114601560,0,b1          0033765345,91    304294596921,0,15040113501560,132,15040610170260,N,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0000000000000000,0,0,2,,27,b1          0031r69144,1
```

This is the format of the file. Each line will be like this.

---

#### Explanation:

The program expects to read 50 variables. So it expects 49 `,`. When a file is like above and it has less variables i am facing an error. So I need a script in unix to add missing `,` in order to take them as `null`.

Comment: I can not share the code because there is a company Confidentiality agreement.. The program just reads each line and put values into variables until line ends. i need to cound ',' of each line and add  ',,,,,,,' in order to insert the missing variables as null..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603566/count-occurrences-of-a-char-in-plain-text-file     This is something similar but i need to count ',' and not replace it.. Just add 49(50 variables so 49 ',') - (count of the current ',' ) in every line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following awk code:

```
awk -F"," 'NF < 50 {printf $0; for(i = NF; i < 50; ++i)  printf ","; printf "\n" }' file
```

produces

```
9,15040113501460,0,b1          0035569144,91    302317960883,0,15040113501460,132,15040614170560,N,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0000000000000000,0,0,2,,27,b1          003st69144,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
9,15350114601560,0,b1          0033765345,91    304294596921,0,15040113501560,132,15040610170260,N,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0000000000000000,0,0,2,,27,b1          0031r69144,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

here, `NF` is the number of fields in each line, `F` is the field separator. The rule sasys that if you have less then 50 fields (49 commas), we will add those missing to the end.

Comment: Actually this script is just printing.. I want it to overwrite the data inside the file.. Is it possible without a temp file?

Comment: @cgxanth Yes, you can write `awk ... file > newfile` and have the content in the newfile (don't overwrite your input file, that doesn't work). Alternatively, gnu awk has some kind of inline editing mode. As a note, I'm unsure if my script skips lines with 50 fields but prints them or if it omits them. You should check that.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the same approach, but I noticed that it produces an extra comma at the end, so I tweaked the original to not add a comma at the end:

```sh
awk -F, 'NF <= 50 {printf $0; for(i = NF; i < 50; ++i)  printf ","; printf "\n" }'
```