# Count the number of a given character in a file

Tags: bash, unix

I need to count - in bash - the number of a given (single byte) character in a file. For example: count the number of commas, or dots or uppercase 'C' or... any other character.

Basically I need a *generalized* version of `wc -l` to count any single byte character (not just new lines) contained in a certain file.

I have to use it with very large files (several GB) so it has to be fast and resource efficient. Ideally the same level of performances you have with `wc -l` if you had to count new-lines.

Comment: Just write a trivial program in C. It's both trivial and efficient.

Comment: @4ae1e1: agreed... wrote a program in C comparing one word at a time (same approach as `wc`). Updating my results here below...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603566/count-occurrences-of-a-char-in-plain-text-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting here the results of a few tests for documentation purposes...
I did count the number of dots in a file containing 1,807,076,940 bytes and 100ML lines. Each line contains exactly one dot:

```
$ time wc -l xnorm.dat # takes 1.047 seconds(this count new-lines)
$ time grep -o '\.' xnorm.dat | wc -l # takes 87.443 seconds
$ time awk -v RS='.' 'END{print NR-1}' xnorm.dat # takes 53.947 seconds
$ time tr -d -C '\.' < xnorm.dat | wc -c # takes 3.732 seconds
```

**Edit**

Wrote a small program (fcc=fast char counter) in C as per 4ae1e1 suggestion:

```
$ time fcc -i xnorm.dat -c \. # takes 1.327 seconds
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `grep -o` with `wc -l`. e.g. to count # of letter `C` in your input file:

```
grep -Fo 'C' file | wc -l
```

To get this done in **single command** you can use `gnu awk` with custom `RS`:

```
awk -v RS='C' 'END{print NR-1}' file
```

Comment: I had a similar requirement recently, to filter very large text files (> 1Gb) and AWK was the fastest of all methods.